# Creating multiple sheets in CSV file

Tags: java, csv, web-development-server, supercsv

I am using superCSV to write data in csv format in my code. Its working absolutely fine and very efficiently , but now my requirement changed . I need to write multiple sheets in single xls file which is very time consuming task. So is there is any way in supercsv by which i can write multiple sheet data in single csv file and will send it to client, so that when client open this csv file in MS-Excel, he can see multiple sheets rather than me generating the excel file with with multiple sheets and sending it to client.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

CSV is a very simple format, and does not have the concept of a "sheet".
So, no, it's not possible directly.
The only thing that I can suggest is to send multiple csv files to the client, perhaps as a .zip file, and have the client unizp it and import one sheet at a time into Excel.

If you need it to open directly in the browser, you'll need to go with an xls file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the api here.

http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html

I'm not familiar SuperCsv please don't beat me up too bad if I'm wrong...
Can't you just set **CsvPreference** to **EXCEL**

Comment: The preference just sets how the quotes and delimiters are set up. It doesn't (and can't) introduce the concept of a "sheet" into the csv format.

Comment: Oh, I get that. Thank you for taking the time to give me some better insight.